# Table view inside scroll view: expand table view on scrolling and hide view above it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to hide the view above my table view when I scroll down and show it again when scrolling up. That kind of behavior is implemented in many apps. How can I manage to do that?

Comment: Table view is a scroll view, so why nest them? Apple explicitly says not to do this. `UITableView` has all of the scroll view delegates built in so just access them there. Address that problem first before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the height constraint of the view above the table

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let viewY = scrollview.contentOffset.y

    self.topViewH.constant = (viewY == 0) ? 200 : 0

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: It is not recommended to put a tableView inside a scrollView (basically tableView itself is a scrollView). Both iOS and user will get confused how/where to scroll because of scroll inside a inside.

My solution: For your usecase, you can put your view (which you want to hide on scroll down and show on scroll up) in the tableview header itself.